# Single-entry Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, sweden, schengen-visas

I am an Indian passport holder and travelling from Mumbai to Stockholm for office work for 8 days. I have a single-entry Schengen visa for 10 days issued by the Sweden embassy in New Delhi.

I will be travelling from Mumbai to Stockholm via Amsterdam (with a layover of 2 hours and 45 minutes in Amsterdam). But while returning from Stockholm to Mumbai, I have an Air France flight, which is from Stockholm to Mumbai via Paris and has a 19-hour layover in Paris.

Will I be able to go out of CDG airport and explore the beautiful city of Paris during this layover, since I have a single-entry Schengen visa?

Answer (score 3):

The "single entry" goes for the whole Schengen area, and as the Netherlands, Sweden and France are all members, your single entry will start when you land in Amsterdam and end when you take off from Paris.

Comment: So technically speaking...they will not have any passport control procedure at Arlanda airport as Air France first stop is at Paris...when I will take the flight from Paris to Mumbai...at that time they will stamp my VISA as out...correct? I want to add over here that I have a business visa and not tourist visa...will it have any effect?

Answer (score 1):

You'll enter Schengen area only once - landing in Amsterdam. So single entry visa will be sufficient for your described itinerary.

Comment: So technically speaking...they will not have any passport control procedure at Arlanda airport as Air France first stop is at Paris...when I will take the flight from Paris to Mumbai...at that time they will stamp my VISA as out...correct?I want to add over here that I have a business visa and not tourist visa...will it have any effect?

Comment: Yes, no passport control. Type of visa does not matter

Answer (score 1):

From Amsterdam to Paris, nobody should check your passport. Airlines could check it as identity check, but they will not check visa. The same, police could do some random controls, but that is just to check that you have a valid document and visa.

So, you enter in Schengen Area in Amsterdam, and you will exit it on Paris. On the other flights there is no immigration check.

Comment: So technically speaking...they will not have any passport control procedure at Arlanda airport as Air France first stop is at Paris...when I will take the flight from Paris to Mumbai...at that time they will stamp my VISA as out...correct? I want to add over here that I have a business visa and not tourist visa...will it have any effect?

Comment: Yes. As a Schengen Area citizen, if I take the flight between Amsterdam and Stockholm, I should not have any kind of passport control. So you will not pass to any check. In case you need to have the passport control, you need voluntarily go there (this is not your case, but in case of residency or non-schengen visa)